# Is it possible to bind an object elements according to the value of a variable in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Suppose that I have an object like this:

```
var myObj = {
    item1:{},
    item2:{},
    item3:{},
    ...
};
```

I also have another variable (e.g:`itemHolder`) that could get values like `item1`, `item2`  and so on.

I want to bind the object elements in my view. Is there any way to bind that according to the value of my variable? A solution like below:

```
{{myObj.[itemHolder]}}
```

Comment: Yes, just remove . from above expression and it will work

Comment: Thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that both variables are declared on your scope, yes, you can do it using javascript bracket notation like so:

```
$scope.myObj = {
    item1: {},
    item2: {},
    item3: {},
    ...
};

$scope.itemHolder = 'item1';
```

Then you can interpolate the value like below:

```
{{ myObj[itemHolder] }} // {}
```

Working snippet:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('AppController', function($scope) {

    $scope.myObj = {
      item1: { a: 1 },
      item2: { b: 2 },
      item3: { c: 3 }
    };

    $scope.itemHolder = 'item1';

  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppController">
  Type the prop name<br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="itemHolder"><br>
  {{ myObj[itemHolder] }}
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, It's Ok. I really felt like a stupid! I already used it many times but... lol!